# Librerias glut y glui

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Qué tal, estaba siguiendo los pasos de un tutorial para trabajar con unas librerías para C++ que permiten trabajar con interfaz gráfica. Todo lo seguí al pie de la letra, aunque de todos modos me surgió un error. Así que en include incluí la ruta de la libreria sin embargo me muestra lo siguiente. Siento mucho si no es una pregunta "adecuada" al objetivo de la página, estoy algo frustrado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si sirve de algo, anexo el link del respectivo tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bpeb3jf6tks&t=291s

Edit1: Adjunto el link con las capturas de la configuración de mi proyecto https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MbQvAC0ngqfXT-YDK4-W5ir2hlvrVadj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tu pregunta es acorde al sitio. Sin embargo, la puedes mejorar agregando el código l. Te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir capturas de cómo se ve la configuración de tu proyecto? De **Link Settings** y las secciones **Compiler** y **Linker** en **Search Directories** para asegurarnos de que lo hiciste bien.

Comment: @Mateo claro, son varias capturas, las subiré a drive y añado el link editando la publicación

Comment: Edita la pregunta y subelas aquí por favor. La idea de este sitio es poder ayudar a más personas que solo el que pregunta. Para ello es mejor si no dependes de sitios o recursos externos.

Comment: @Mateo no me deja añadir tantas imágenes el propio editor, cualquiera tiene acceso al contenido que compartí de drive igualmente.

Comment: A mí también me pasa ese problema. En build log dice *skipping incompatible lib/libfreeglut.a when searching for -lfreeglut*. Investigué un poco y parece que el problema surge de tratar de usar una librería de 32 bits (las que comparte el tipo del video son de 32 bits) con un compilador para 64 bits.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que es una librería vieja y desactualizada, considera usar opciones más nuevas y con soporte. [ImGUI](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) es una muy buena opción de moda. Además puedes cambiar su aspecto. Soporta DirectX, OpenGL y Vulkan. Adicionalmente necesitarás una librería para la creación de ventanas como GLFW o SDL. Si vas a usar OpenGL, es recomendable usar un cargador de funciones (de preferencia uno como GLEW, o GLAD que de a poco le está robando lugar).

Comment: Muchas gracias @Mateo, tomaré tus recomendaciones.